# How build multi sql insert query with dependency upon each other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables (MySQL):

```
productSize: {
   id,
   article,
   size,
   weight
}
productPrice: {
   id,
   sizeID,
   price
}
```

sizeID - primery id form productSize table. I need to make one insert into productSize table, then miltiple insert or update into productPrice.

I try something like this:

```
foreach($arrProductSize as $objSize) {              
    /*
    Insert into productSize here. Get id of new row by mysqli_insert_id()
    */

    foreach($arrProductPrice as $objPrice) {
       /*
          Insert or update into productPrice. 
          Save primery id from productSize new row into productPrice new row.
       */
    }
}
```

But I wish to join all sql query into one single query. Is it possible? If connection fail on productPrice sql query all procedure must start over again and in productSize table will be a lot of not correct items.

I wish to use:

```
mysqli_multi_query($dbi, "INSERT INTO productSize(article,size,weight) VALUES ('','','');INSERT INTO productPrice(sizeID,price) VALUES ('4','');");
```

But sizeID(=4) i need to get pfor prevois insert query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that select query in insert statment 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

```
foreach($arrProductSize as $objSize){
    $query = "INSERT INTO productSize(article,size,weight) VALUES ('','','');";
    foreach($arrProductPrice as $objPrice) {
          $query .= "INSERT INTO productPrice(sizeID,price)
                SELECT id, '{$bjPrice->price}' FROM productSize order BY id desc limit 1; "
    }
    mysqli_query($dbi,$query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` can only insert into one table at a time, so it's not possible to combine the `productSize` and `productPrice` inserts. But you can do all the `productPrice` inserts at once.

```
foreach ($arrProductSize as $objSize) {
    // insert into productSize here
    $psid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    $pp_array = array();
    foreach ($arrProductPrice as $objPrice) {
        $pp_array[] = "({$objPrice->id}, $psid, {$objPrice->price})";
    }
    $pp_query = "INSERT INTO productPrice (id, sizeID, price) VALUES " . implode(', ', $pp_array) . " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sizeID = VALUES(sizeID), price = VALUES(price)";
    mysqli_query($conn, $pp_query);
}
```